# Why Are ICommand Properties Treated Specially by Bindings?

Tags: wpf, binding, icommand

So far, I had the impression that WPF generally looks at the actual type of an object it gets via a binding or in any other way to determine what templates, styles and representation to use. However, I am now confronted with a situation which makes it seem like WPF (also?) looks at the declared property type for some reason.

This is an exemplary view model:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

public class SimpleViewModel
{
    private class MyExampleCommand : ICommand
    {
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "test";
        }
    }

    private ICommand exampleCommand;

    public ICommand ExampleCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (exampleCommand == null)
            {
                exampleCommand = new MyExampleCommand();
            }
            return exampleCommand;
        }
    }
}
```

Use an instance of that class as a data context in a window and add this button:

```
<Button>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ExampleCommand}"/>
</Button>
```

In the running application, the button will be empty. If `SimpleViewModel.ExampleCommand` is typed to `object` instead of `ICommand`, `test` will be shown as the label on the button as expected.

**What is wrong here? Does WPF really treat objects differently based on the *declared* type of the property that returned them? Can this be worked around, and are any other types beside `ICommand` affected?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ToString()` is declared on `object` and `ICommand` is not an `object` it is an interface. It is only **assignable** to `object`.

The binding system does not, as you already said, differentiate on the declared type. But the default `IValueConverter` used in the case of conversion to `string` does.

Internally the framework uses a `DefaultValueConverter` when no user defined converter is given. In the `Create` method you can see why interfaces will act differently then objects here (look for the specific check of `sourceType.IsInterface`):

```
internal static IValueConverter Create(Type sourceType,
                                    Type targetType, 
                                    bool targetToSource,
                                    DataBindEngine engine)
{
    TypeConverter typeConverter; 
    Type innerType;
    bool canConvertTo, canConvertFrom; 
    bool sourceIsNullable = false; 
    bool targetIsNullable = false;

    // sometimes, no conversion is necessary
    if (sourceType == targetType ||
        (!targetToSource && targetType.IsAssignableFrom(sourceType)))
    { 
        return ValueConverterNotNeeded;
    } 

    // the type convert for System.Object is useless.  It claims it can
    // convert from string, but then throws an exception when asked to do 
    // so.  So we work around it.
    if (targetType == typeof(object))
    {
        // The sourceType here might be a Nullable type: consider using 
        // NullableConverter when appropriate. (uncomment following lines)
        //Type innerType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(sourceType); 
        //if (innerType != null) 
        //{
        //    return new NullableConverter(new ObjectTargetConverter(innerType), 
        //                                 innerType, targetType, true, false);
        //}

        // 
        return new ObjectTargetConverter(sourceType, engine);
    } 
    else if (sourceType == typeof(object)) 
    {
        // The targetType here might be a Nullable type: consider using 
        // NullableConverter when appropriate. (uncomment following lines)
        //Type innerType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(targetType);
        // if (innerType != null)
        // { 
        //     return new NullableConverter(new ObjectSourceConverter(innerType),
        //                                  sourceType, innerType, false, true); 
        // } 

        // 
        return new ObjectSourceConverter(targetType, engine);
    }

    // use System.Convert for well-known base types 
    if (SystemConvertConverter.CanConvert(sourceType, targetType))
    { 
        return new SystemConvertConverter(sourceType, targetType); 
    }

    // Need to check for nullable types first, since NullableConverter is a bit over-eager;
    // TypeConverter for Nullable can convert e.g. Nullable<DateTime> to string
    // but it ends up doing a different conversion than the TypeConverter for the
    // generic's inner type, e.g. bug 1361977 
    innerType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(sourceType);
    if (innerType != null) 
    { 
        sourceType = innerType;
        sourceIsNullable = true; 
    }
    innerType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(targetType);
    if (innerType != null)
    { 
        targetType = innerType;
        targetIsNullable = true; 
    } 
    if (sourceIsNullable || targetIsNullable)
    { 
        // single-level recursive call to try to find a converter for basic value types
        return Create(sourceType, targetType, targetToSource, engine);
    }

    // special case for converting IListSource to IList
    if (typeof(IListSource).IsAssignableFrom(sourceType) && 
        targetType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IList))) 
    {
        return new ListSourceConverter(); 
    }

    // Interfaces are best handled on a per-instance basis.  The type may
    // not implement the interface, but an instance of a derived type may. 
    if (sourceType.IsInterface || targetType.IsInterface)
    { 
        return new InterfaceConverter(sourceType, targetType); 
    }

    // try using the source's type converter
    typeConverter = GetConverter(sourceType);
    canConvertTo = (typeConverter != null) ? typeConverter.CanConvertTo(targetType) : false;
    canConvertFrom = (typeConverter != null) ? typeConverter.CanConvertFrom(targetType) : false; 

    if ((canConvertTo || targetType.IsAssignableFrom(sourceType)) && 
        (!targetToSource || canConvertFrom || sourceType.IsAssignableFrom(targetType))) 
    {
        return new SourceDefaultValueConverter(typeConverter, sourceType, targetType, 
                                               targetToSource && canConvertFrom, canConvertTo, engine);
    }

    // if that doesn't work, try using the target's type converter 
    typeConverter = GetConverter(targetType);
    canConvertTo = (typeConverter != null) ? typeConverter.CanConvertTo(sourceType) : false; 
    canConvertFrom = (typeConverter != null) ? typeConverter.CanConvertFrom(sourceType) : false; 

    if ((canConvertFrom || targetType.IsAssignableFrom(sourceType)) && 
        (!targetToSource || canConvertTo || sourceType.IsAssignableFrom(targetType)))
    {
        return new TargetDefaultValueConverter(typeConverter, sourceType, targetType,
                                               canConvertFrom, targetToSource && canConvertTo, engine); 
    }

    // nothing worked, give up 
    return null;
}
```

According to the documentation you should provide a user defined `IValueConverter` when binding to a property of different type than the dependency property you are binding to as relying on `ToString` being called is an implementation detail of the frameworks default conversion mechanism (and is undocumented as far as i know, it only states default and fallback values for well defined circumstances) and could change at any moment.

Comment: That's true, but why is WPF looking at the declared property type in the first place? Shouldn't it just look at what is actually returned?

Comment: Edited. InterfaceConverter just behaves differently then the others. This is from the C#4.0 source. So my initial answer was a bit off, it is more because Type.IsInterface will return different values for different declared property types.

Comment: Something interesting I noticed is that if I declare my property as `MyExampleCommand` (making that type `public` beforehand), the button will still remain empty. If `MyExampleCommand` does not implement `ICommand` any more, `ToString` is properly called. How is that related, i.e. why does implementing some interface that is not directly mentioned in the propery declaration change anything?

Comment: Because all of what you are using is undocumented internal framework implementation. You could dig down into the code for every case and see what it does, but it can and will change every release. Just use a custom converter and you wont have to deal with it.

Comment: I've accepted this answer as it points out a viable method to work around the issue, even though MSDN articles such as [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc700358.aspx) or [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970558.aspx) suggest that `ToString` is indeed called as a default case in certain circumstances. I will perform some further tests to determine whether that really only refers to data templates.