# WPF not calling TypeConverter when DependencyProperty is interface

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create TypeConverter which will convert my custom type to ICommand if I am binding it to Button Command.

Unfortunetly WPF is not calling my converter.

Converter:

```
public class CustomConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(ICommand))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(
        ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(ICommand))
        {
            return new DelegateCommand<object>(x => { });
        }

        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Button  Content="Execute" Command="{Binding CustomObject}"  />
```

Converter will be invoked if I will bind to content like:

```
<Button  Content="{Binding CustomObject}"  />
```

Any ideas how I can get TypeConverter to work?

Comment: Very interesting. I have confirmed that the type being an interface is the problem. Test code: http://pastebin.com/EsMguMx5 - the converter is never called, but simply change `IDestinationThing` to `DestinationThing` in the dependency property definition, and it will start working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it if you create an `ITypeConverter`. But you'll have to use it explicitly, so it is more xaml to write. On the other hand, sometimes being explicit is a good thing. If you are trying to avoid having to declare the converter in the `Resources`, you can derive from `MarkupExtension`. So your converter would look like this:

```
public class ToCommand : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, 
                          Type targetType, 
                          object parameter, 
                          CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType != tyepof(ICommand))
            return Binding.DoNothing;

        return new DelegateCommand<object>(x => { });
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, 
                              Type targetType, 
                              object parameter, 
                              CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

And then you'd use it like:

```
<Button Content="Execute" 
        Command="{Binding CustomObject, Converter={lcl:ToCommand}}" />
```

Comment: I would like to avoid adding converter.

Comment: Well, you can always implement `ICommand` (explicitly if you don't want it to be exposed). If WPF won't run your `TypeConverter` for an interface, those are pretty much your only options. Also, the answer to this question seems to describe what is going on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17728436/why-are-icommand-properties-treated-specially-by-bindings

Comment: I understand it's due to crappy impl of InterfaceConverter, was hoping to find some workaround that would not require Implementing ICommand or using converter. Right now I am converting object by hand before binding.

Comment: Unfortunately, you won't be able to use a `TypeConverter` unless MS changes the implementation of WPF in a future update. So you're going to either have to use your current work-around, an `IValueConverter`, or some other non-`TypeConverter` method of doing so.